# Get and set inline styles with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, inline-styles

Is there a way to get and set inline styles of DOM elements inside an HTML fragment with PHP? Example:

```
<div style="background-color:black"></div>
```

I need to get whether the `background-color` is `black` and if it is, change it to `white`. **(This is an example and not the actual goal)**

I tried phpQuery, but it lacks the .css() method, while the [branch that implements it](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery/pull/2) doesn't seem to work (at least for me).

Basically, **what I need is a port of jQuery's .css() method to PHP.**

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible using just php I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't know if there's an easier way, but a basic starting point would be PHP's DOM functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: How are you getting the HTML? You may want to use a XML/DOM parser.

Comment: Currently I'm using phpQuery to get elements that I need.

Answer (score 2):

Per Ryan P's good suggestion above, the `PHP` `DOM` functions may help you out. Something like this might do what you want with that particular example.

```
$my_url = 'index.php';
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTMLfile($my_url);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $div_style = $div->getAttribute('style');
    if ($div_style && $div_style=='background-color:black;') {
    $div->setAttribute('style','background-color:white;');
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I've been thinking along these lines as well. But what if there's more than one inline style `<div style="display: none; background-color: white">`? Will that require writing some kind of a parser? Knowing how hard this stuff is and how vulnerable it is to hacks, I'm wary of doing it all by myself. Is there a plugin I can use?

Comment: I'm not sure of any plugins, but you could use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to see if the substring `background:white;` exists, then act accordingly.